# How can I find an XML element by one of its attributes, and retrieve the value of its other attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing

For example, I have the following in an XML file:

```
<decisionPoint fileName="5">
<choice label="ARIN, RIPE, APNIC" goTo="5aa"/>
<choice label="Whois.org, Network Solutions" goTo="5aa"/>
<choice label="Google, Bing, Yahoo" goTo="5c"/>
</decisionPoint>
```

I have the value `fileName=5`, and I have the `label` value `Whois.org, Network Solutions`, and I need to retrieve the value of `goTo` on the `<choice>` which has that label value. How can I go about doing this with jquery?

Do I need to make an array of the entire xml file? If so, what after that? I understand finding an element by its name, but I'm not sure what direction to go in as far as finding the element with X attribute, then retrieving the value of Y attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery lets you issue queries to search inside a parsed XML fragment :

```
var xml = '<decisionPoint fileName="5">\
<choice label="ARIN, RIPE, APNIC" goTo="5aa"/>\
<choice label="Whois.org, Network Solutions" goTo="5aa"/>\
<choice label="Google, Bing, Yahoo" goTo="5c"/>\
</decisionPoint>';
var $xml = $(xml);
```

then

```
var gt = $xml.find('choice[label="Whois.org, Network Solutions"]').attr('goTo');
```

to find the element with the exact attribute value and retrieve the value of `goTo`.

Or this to find by part of the attribute :

```
var gt = $xml.find('choice[label*="Whois.org"]').attr('goTo');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/obecid/1/edit) (open the console)